# Does Google Analytics track window.location and Meta Refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, http, redirect, google-analytics

If I redirect a user with `window.location` or Meta Refresh or `header('Location:')` from xxxy.com to yyyx.com, then Google Analytics will show xxxy.com as traffic source or not?

It's important for me because of an adserver. I'm using `window.location` right now, and Google Analytics and my ad server have very different statics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 types of redirects. Google Analytics treats each of them differently. But, the one consistent thread is that it looks to the value `document.referrer`. So, when in doubt, just check.

1. HTTP Redirect (`Location:...`): Google Analytics cannot see this redirect, so if a user goes from A to B, and B triggers an HTTP redirect to C, Google Analytics will see A as the referrer. (For example, clicked `bit.ly` links never get `bit.ly` tracked as the referrer when users get redirected through `bit.ly`).
2. META Refresh: Google Analytics will not see this as a "clean" redirect. So, if a user goes from A to B, and B triggers a META refresh redirect to C, Google Analytics will see B as the referrer.
3. `window.location`: Google Analytics  will not see this as a "clean" redirect. So, if a user goes from A to B, and B triggers a window.location redirect to C, Google Analytics will see B as the referrer, except in older versions of Internet Explorer (which will not list a referrer value in `document.referrer` for JavaScript redirects.)