# Window.location causes Google Analytics to stop working

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-analytics

I have a piece of code where I do a bunch of Google Analytics event tracking.  Say a user clicks on a button or a tab, there will be an event tracking sent out.

But as soon as I click a button which downloads a CSV, the code being used is below, all the tracking stops working in Firefox.  Other browsers continue tracking the events correctly.

```
window.location= '/campaigns/coupon-links/get-coupons.csv';
```

I tried using `window.open('/campaigns/coupon-links/get-coupons.csv')` and that made the tracking work in Firefox, but I am perplexed on why window.location would cause just the Google Analytics to stop working.  I checked all the events listeners and objects on the page, everything still is declared and nothing throws an error.

Any clues?

Comment: Perhaps something related here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256457/does-google-analytics-track-window-location-and-meta-refresh

Comment: Use window.top.location = 'url';

Comment: @EnriqueQuero - any reason to do so?