# Google and W3C says to avoid using Meta Refresh? What to do instead when using Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, google-analytics

So I have a website that has moved (permanently to a new location) so I use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='locationA'">
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.location.href='locationB';
</script>
```

When considering Google Analytics if a user lands on locationA via google search, old vanity url, or old ad, or even using their bookmark...and gets redirected to location B, would the document.referrer still be accurate?

I ask because I did some searching and Google Webmaster Tools and Google's John Mueller both state that its not recommended to use a meta refresh ([BenoHead.com](https://benohead.com/http-redirect-meta-refresh-frame-javascript/)).

But then Yahel's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256457/does-google-analytics-track-window-location-and-meta-refresh) states that GA can still track but treats them differently.

So how would I do his redirect in the correct way and maintain a clean GA? because according to Yahel a Meta Refresh and a window.location aren't clean, and HTTP Redirect isn't seen.

All advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "clean" I think what you're concerned with is the document referrer data. This information is usually passed in the header of the request. When you use meta and js redirects it will use the page that's doing the redirect as the document referrer, this means you'll miss the true referrer.

What you need to do is implement redirects on the server level, when the old page is requested, the server needs to reply back with a 301 status code indicating "moved permanently", this is good practice for SEO as well. You'll need to do this either through .htaccess or server-side scripts (node, php, .net, etc)

HTTP Status: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Referrer field: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: Thank you! sorry i failed to mention that I am using a CMS/CRM tool called Luminate Online. So what I have is a pagebuilder and the page wrapper (head of the document lives). I can easily use JS but not sure how I can incorporate PHP into it for server-side scripts.

Comment: You can try this: https://www.blackbaud.com/support/howto/coveo/luminate-online/Subsystems/Luminate_CMS/Concepts/Admin_CMS_Working_with_URL_Aliases.html

Comment: Oh wow the Luminate online help is so clunky I could not find this. thanks xtothel!

Comment: Yea the first link that came up talked about using meta and js to redirect, but further down I found that documentation. Glad it helped!